# Semi Transparent page over other page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8 application and I wish to add a semi transparent layer/page kind of thing over my current page to show some instructions to use the app to the user at start. Do someone know of some element or way with which this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have overlap of two pages. However, for an overlay, you can simply add an extra grid and position everything inside it. Then you can use the `Visibility` property of your overlay Grid to show/hide the tutorial. Here's an example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"> <!--This is your root grid-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
            <!--put actual content of the page here-->
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="OverlayGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <!--put content of the overlay here-->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Now, whenever you want to display the overlay, do this in your code:

```
OverlayGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i also wish to add Application Bar on that overlay page to prevent my layout from scrolling up when Application Bar is present. And Application Bar can't be added inside a grid

Comment: You should use the Opacity Property instead of Visibility for archieving the semi transparent effect. Don't forget to set the Visibility to Collapsed when the Opacity becomes 0.

Set the Application bar in the code behind and fill it with the needed buttons depending on which page is shown. Do you need some code for that?

Comment: @Robin-ManuelThiel I think Opacity is suited better on the contents of the grid rather than the grid itself.

Comment: Try it out, I'm sure this is exactly what you want! :)